# PHP Get last five words from .txt-file using file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, string, output, file-get-contents

I'm looking for a functioning way of reading the *last*, say, 5 words from a .txt file using file_get_contents while long-polling. I've tried to work on a solution using the commented code below, but it breaks the long-polling – which works fine when displaying the full contents of a .txt-file.

I looked at the `offset` parameter for file_get_contents as well, but I don't know how to do a good (or functioning) adaption of that in my code. I guess that'd involve first counting all the words in said .txt file (which in itself is dynamic) then taking that number of words minus 5 somehow? There's probably an easier solution than that, and if not how do I go about to work it out with an alternative solution?

**get_data.php**

```
$id = $_COOKIE["currentID"];

$filepath = 'stories/'.$id.'.txt';

if (file_exists($filepath)) {

$lastmodif = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = filemtime($filepath);

while($currentmodif <= $lastmodif){
    sleep(1);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filepath);
}

        // I've tried:
        // Attempt to getting the last five words of .txt file, does NOT work 
        $str = file_get_contents($filepath);
        $words = explode(' ', $str);
        $last = join(" ", array_slice($words, -5, 5));

  $response = array();
  /*   $response['data'] = file_get_contents($filepath); */  //use if not attempting to get last 5 words
  $response['data'] = $last; //part of "what I've tried"
  $response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;

echo json_encode($response);  

}

else{
    // if file doesn't exist
    echo('nada data, son.');
}
?>
```

**application.js** (for context)

```
$(function(){

    $.longpolling({
        pollURL: './get_data.php',
        successFunction: pollSuccess,
        errorFunction: pollError
    });
});

function pollSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
  var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
  $('#response').html(json['data']);

document.getElementById('notificationsound').play();
console.log('file updated');

}

function pollError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
console.log('Long Polling Error: ' + textStatus);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do:

```
$lastfive = explode(" ", trim(preg_replace("/^([\s\S]+)(( ([^ ]+)){5})$/m", "$2", $code)));
```

Also, you should **never** use `eval` when parsing code retrieved from a server. Try using `JSON.parse(data)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on not using `eval`. Your example almost works perfect, it does indeed only show the last five words which is exactly what I want to achieve – but it also removes all spaces between the words; `This is a test to see what happens` becomes `testtoseewhathappens`. Also, I'm curious as to what `"$2"` is in this case?

Comment: Try removing the `explode` function from the example above. That will output a string that you can then `data.split(' ')` with javascript rather than outputting and parsing a JSON object.
`$2` refers to the second match in the regular expression pattern in `preg_replace`. The pattern matches any characters `([\s\S])` from the beginning of the string `^`, then a group of five words `((...){5})`, within which an opening space and word are matched ` ([a-zA-Z]+)` until the end of the string `$`. [Have a read about regular expressions in PHP](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll definitely have a look at the use of expressions then. One last thing, I noticed that the original code you provided breaks upon receiving a string that contains diacritics, such as å ä ö, is this due to the use of expressions as well (since it probably splits the UTF-8 characters in the .txt file)?

Comment: Whoops! Have updated the code. `[a-zA-Z]` has changed to `[^ ]`.